# Anchore - Error: could not access anchore service (user=admin url=http://localhost:8228/v1/)

Tags: jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

I downloaded docker-compose.yaml file from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/anchore/anchore-engine/master/scripts/docker-compose/docker-compose.yaml

And then docker-compose pull

After that, I started the engine using docker-compose up -d

Now, for accessing I installed anchorecli using pip.

But I see Error: could not access anchore service (user=admin url=http://localhost:8228/v1/). Please help. I guess the url is wrong or i don't know what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure something.
Here is the steps:

```
export ANCHORE_CLI_USER='username_of_anchore'
export ANCHORE_CLI_PASS='pass_of-anchore'
```

now try

```
anchore-cli system status
```

you will get output now.
Now do whatever you needed...